# Ruby on Rails - Scoping resources by current_account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, multi-tenant, user-accounts

I’m new to ruby on rails and I’m a bit stuck with what the best next step is in a multi-tenancy application I’m building.

Basically I want to scope resources by account_id, so I have created a method and helper called current_account in my accounts base_controller.

However, the tutorial I’m following scopes current_account by subdomain which I do not want to do. So I need a way to identify the current user’s account_id so that that I can have a resource variable @contact = current_account.contacts."all".

Do I need to make a new association between the user and account model so that I can use the current_user helper to define the current account id or is there a better way? If so, what is the best way to do this?

**Background** 
The first user who signs up becomes the account owner. Account owners can then invite other users to the account. I'm using the devise gem. Resources are scoped by account so that only users linked to an account can see the records belonging to that account.

**Base Controller**

```
module Accounts
  class BaseController < ApplicationController
    def current_account
      @current_account ||= ?????
    end
    helper_method :current_account

    def owner?
      current_account.owner == current_user
    end
    helper_method :owner?
  end
end
```

**Contacts (my resource) Controller**

```
module Accounts
  class ContactsController < Accounts::BaseController
    def index
        @contact = current_account.contacts.all
    end
  end
end
```

**Account Model**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner

  validates :subdomain, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  has_many :contacts
  has_many :invitations
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

**Invitation Model**

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

**Membership Model**

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  scope module: "accounts" do
  resources 'dashboard'
  resources 'contacts'
  resources :invitations, only: [:new, :create] do 
    member do
      get :accept
      patch :accepted
    end
  end
  resources :users, only: [:index, :destroy]
end
```

**Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170124002015) do

  create_table "accounts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.string   "subdomain"
  end

  add_index "accounts", ["subdomain"], name: "index_accounts_on_subdomain"

  create_table "contacts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "comments"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "account_id"
  end

  add_index "contacts", ["account_id"], name: "index_contacts_on_account_id"

  create_table "invitations", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "token"
  end

  add_index "invitations", ["account_id"], name: "index_invitations_on_account_id"
  add_index "invitations", ["token"], name: "index_invitations_on_token"

  create_table "memberships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "memberships", ["account_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_account_id"
  add_index "memberships", ["user_id"], name: "index_memberships_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at this gem? https://github.com/elabs/pundit
it enables you to create policies for your users. Im pretty sure you can take it from there.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it will work for me. I'm going to test it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible associations between users and accounts:

1. users have many accounts
2. users belong to an account

In the first case, the tenant cannot be set from the current_user, because it's unclear which account should be used as the current tenant. The membership table in the schema.rb indicates this is the approach taken by the tutorial you mentioned. Loading the account by subdomain helps specify which account shall be used as the current tenant.

In the second case, every user has just one account. Users get an account_id, the membership table becomes obsolete, and you can load the current tenant like so:

```
def current_account
  @current_account ||= current_user.account
end
```

> Do I need to make a new association between the user and account model
>   so that I can use the current_user helper to define the current
>   account id or is there a better way? If so, what is the best way to do
>   this?

It seems to me that you want to take the second approach, which requires that  an account `has_many` users and a user `belongs_to` an account.

Comment: What is the best way to make the association within the Accounts Controller so that the account_id saves to each new user? Because it also needs to keep the owner association so that the owner of the account has a higher level of access and create more users in the future.